# I'm looking for a syntax highlighter that works on custom language

Tags: parsing, syntax-highlighting

I want a syntax highlighter which can highlight my own syntax. Words like `continue`, `:i`, and `loop_to`. With the ability to add new words. I thought about AJAX, but maybe you can give me easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) might be what you're looking for. I've been very happy with it in the past. You can add your own language syntax by [creating a language file](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/geshi-doc.html#language-files).

Just plop that somewhere on a PHP-enabled server with your own language file.